# vector product per element of matrices

Tags: python, numpy

I have two matrices of shape (2,3):

```
a=[[a_11, a_12, a_13], [a_21, a_22, a_23]]
b=[[b_11, b_12, b_13], [b_21, b_22, b_23]]
```

I want to calculate following vector of shape (2, ):

```
[[a_11, a_12, a_13]*[b_11, b_12, b_13],
 [a_21, a_22, a_23]*[b_21, b_22, b_23]]
```

Namely,

```
[a_11*b_11 + a_12*b_12 + a_13*b_13, a_21*b_21 + a_22*b_22 + a_23*b_23]
```

Is there a built-in operation for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can write

```
(a * b).sum(axis=-1)
```

example:

```
a=np.array([[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4]])
b=np.array([[3, 4, 5], [4, 5, 6]])
(a * b).sum(axis=-1)
#Out:
array([26, 47])
```

Verifying by hand

```
1*3 + 2*4 + 3*5 == 26
2*4 + 3*5 + 4*6 == 47
```

Answer (score 0):

This is A * B', right? Try `np.dot(a, np.transpose(b))` https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html.

Comment: not quite, but close. only the diagnoal elements of the dot product are described by the OP's formula, i.e. `np.diagonal(np.dot(a, b.T))`